# Calling web method in c# without web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is my mistake.
I am trying to call asmx web method without web refernce, but i have an error on line:

```
var result = client.UploadData(WebServiceUrl, data);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

```
 class CallWebMethod
{
    public string CallRemoteWebService()
    {
        string ResponseText = "";

        string WebServiceUrl = "http://192.168.1.3/META/services/ws.asmx"; 
        string WebMethodName = "FillXmlData"; 

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                        var payload = string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
         <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
          <soap:Body>
            <{0} xmlns=""http://www.curs.kz/gdmx/services/"" />
          </soap:Body>
         </soap:Envelope>", WebMethodName);

            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            var result = client.UploadData(WebServiceUrl, data);

            ResponseText = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

        }
        return ResponseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the logs of the called service.

Comment: You need to examine the error on the server, not on the client.
IIS usually logs this in log files.

Comment: Read the error message.  `"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."`  This means that your code did send the request to the web service, and the web service responded with an error.  Check the web service response for more information, or debug the web service itself.  Currently all this code knows is that "something went wrong" on the server.  You have to find out what that something is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to examine/debug the error on the server, not on the client. IIS usually logs this in log files.

Alternatively, you can try to output response to console using `try...catch` block and see if server is returning some additional details:

```
try
{
   string ResponseText = "";

    string WebServiceUrl = "http://192.168.1.3/META/services/ws.asmx"; 
    string WebMethodName = "FillXmlData"; 

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                    var payload = string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
      <soap:Body>
        <{0} xmlns=""http://www.curs.kz/gdmx/services/"" />
      </soap:Body>
     </soap:Envelope>", WebMethodName);

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
        var result = client.UploadData(WebServiceUrl, data);

        ResponseText = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

    }
    return ResponseText;
}
catch (WebException e)
{
   string pageContent = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
   Debug.WriteLine(pageContent);
   throw;
}
```

EDIT: You should add soap action in header (experiment with value) code before calling web service:

```
client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://192.168.1.3/META/services/ws.asmx/FillXmlData")
```

Comment: Server return this : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unable to process the request does not have a valid action parameter. Specify a valid SOAP action.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Comment: What means ?: Unable to process the request does not have a valid action parameter. Specify a valid SOAP action

Comment: See my updated answer...
AND maybe you should use fiddler to see the actual request data of the web service call that works. Then you can use that as a reference and replicate similar request using WebClient.